# Incorrect syntax near 'REPLACE' with MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, replace, liquibase

I have migrated an oracle database to Microsoft SQL Server via liquibase but there are still some SQL statements that don't work. This one looked like this in oracle:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "BP_RESULTS_VIEW" (
BP_ID,                                     
RES_NAME,                                     
RES_LONG_NAME,                                     
MEDIAN,                                    
LOW_HINGE,                                 
HIGH_HINGE,                                
H_SPREAD,                                  
INNER_FENCE_LOW,                           
INNER_FENCE_HIGH,
OUTER_FENCE_LOW,
OUTER_FENCE_HIGH,
LOW_NOTCH,
HIGH_NOTCH,
LOW_ADJACENT_VALUE,
HIGH_ADJACENT_VALUE)
  AS 
SELECT 
r.BP_ID,                                     
rv.RES_NAME,                                     
rv.RES_LONG_NAME,                                     
r.MEDIAN,                                    
r.LOW_HINGE,                                 
r.HIGH_HINGE,                                
r.H_SPREAD,                                  
r.INNER_FENCE_LOW,                           
r.INNER_FENCE_HIGH,
r.OUTER_FENCE_LOW,
r.OUTER_FENCE_HIGH,
r.LOW_NOTCH,
r.HIGH_NOTCH,
r.LOW_ADJACENT_VALUE,
r.HIGH_ADJACENT_VALUE
FROM 
bp_results r, 
results_view_display rv 
WHERE 
CAST (rv.value AS INT) = r.bp_id AND 
rv.type = 'BOX';
```

After migrating it to Microsoft SQL Server it looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW BP_RESULTS_VIEW (BP_ID, RES_NAME, RES_LONG_NAME, MEDIAN,
LOW_HINGE, HIGH_HINGE, H_SPREAD, INNER_FENCE_LOW, INNER_FENCE_HIGH,
OUTER_FENCE_LOW, OUTER_FENCE_HIGH, LOW_NOTCH, HIGH_NOTCH, 
LOW_ADJACENT_VALUE, HIGH_ADJACENT_VALUE) AS SELECT 
r.BP_ID,                                     
rv.RES_NAME,                                     
rv.RES_LONG_NAME,                                     
r.MEDIAN,                                    
r.LOW_HINGE,                                 
r.HIGH_HINGE,                                
r.H_SPREAD,                                  
r.INNER_FENCE_LOW,                           
r.INNER_FENCE_HIGH,
r.OUTER_FENCE_LOW,
r.OUTER_FENCE_HIGH,
r.LOW_NOTCH,
r.HIGH_NOTCH,
r.LOW_ADJACENT_VALUE,
r.HIGH_ADJACENT_VALUE
FROM 
bp_results r, 
results_view_display rv 
WHERE 
CAST (rv.value AS INT) = r.bp_id AND 
rv.type = 'BOX'
GO
```

But when I want to execute it always this error occurs:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'REPLACE'.
```

I don't understand why because the REPLACE statement exists in SQL Server too. It also seems like it doesn't recognize the CAST command. I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17

Comment: `REPLACE` is used for different reasons in SQL Server. You would either use `CREATE VIEW` or `ALTER VIEW` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: You should be using actual JOINS and not joining via the where clause. Evolve!

Comment: Where [in the SQL Server manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference?view=sql-server-2017) did you find `create or replace`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server 2016 SP1 and later (including Azure SQL Database), use [`CREATE OR ALTER VIEW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql) for the equivalent functionality. In earlier SQL Server versions, one must first drop the view and then `CREATE VIEW` and `GRANT` permissions.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server doesn't support `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW`.

Instead, create the view the first time.  Then simply use `ALTER VIEW`.  That is the simplest method.  You can also drop the view and the re-create it.

Comment: doesn't support CREATE VIEW?

Comment: I think you meant "doesn't support CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW".